# ActivationPolicy="Replace" not working in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.1 the default `ActiovationPolicy` changed from `Replace` to `Resume`.

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app and I want to use `ActivationPolicy="Replace"`. Changing `ActivationPolicy="Resume"` to `ActivationPolicy="Replace"` does not work, the app still resumes.

I remember one video from build claiming that this should work, but is this really possible? If so, what is the way to make the app replace instead of resume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps always resume (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/caf0d79a-c55e-4046-afc1-86260c005205/activationpolicyreplace-not-working-in-windows-phone-81?forum=wpdevelop)